# How do I make a serializer for many to many relationships in django if one model is a proxy model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have a project with multiple types of users: admins, drivers and commuters. I made proxy models for the drivers

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Role(models.TextChoices):
        ADMIN = "ADMIN", 'Admin'
        COMMUTER = "COMMUTER", "Commuter"
        DRIVER = "DRIVER", 'Driver'

    base_role= Role.ADMIN

    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Role.choices)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.role = self.base_role
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Driver(User):
    base_role = User.Role.DRIVER
    
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

I want to create a Vehicle model with a many to many relationship with only the drivers and also make serializers to allow me to link instances of drivers to vehicles and also list out all drivers and the vehicles they use. How do I go about this?